# Nodejs express get request not happening

Tags: node.js, express, get, pug

In my nodejs app I'm doing a get request to the storify api but it seems like it doen't happen. My route and view work fine. I am just not sure I am doing my get request right.

I made the application without Express and the jade templating enginge just with plain html and it works fine. I have troubles converting it into an Express app with Jade

here is my app.js file, I took out the part of my route and the get request I hope this gives enough info.

```
 var srmcity = require('./routes/srmcity');
 app.use('/srmcity', srmcity);

 var user = 'dummyuser';
 var story_slug = 'dummy';

 var api_key = "dummykey";
 var username = "dummyuser";
 var _token = "";

 app.get('/',function(req, res,next){
  superagent.get("http://api.storify.com/v1/stories/" + user + "/" + story_slug)
 .query({api_key: api_key,
   username: username,
   _token: _token})
 .set({  Accept: 'application/json' })
 .end(function(e, storifyResponse){
   if (e) next(e);
   //Render template with story object in response body     
   return res.render('srmcity',storifyResponse.body.content);      
 })
})
```

srmcity.js (my route works fine I don't think the problem is here but I just added it)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('tour/srmcity', { title: 'title' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

srmcity.jade (my view where I use handlebars)

```
extends ../layout

block content
 .container
  .row
   h1 {{title}}
   small {{description}}
```